# c++ code slow and exceeding time limit

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

The start and end points of segments are given in vectors *starts* and *ends*. A list of points is given in vector points. Task is to find the number of segments containing each point.
In my solution, each element of *start*, *end* and *point* has been given labels l, p and r respectively and stored in a vector *pairs*. *Pairs* vector is then sorted first by first element and then by second element. Finally I iterate over the pairs vector and increment a variable *coverage* if it is a start point, decrement it if it's an end point and if it is a point then assign the value of coverage to the answer.
The algorithm seems to be correct with a time complexity of O(nlog(n)) but it is exceeding the time limit. What part of the code is slow ?

Code :

```
vector<int> fast_count_segments(vector<int>& starts, vector<int>& ends, vector<int>& points) {
    vector<int> cnt(points.size());
    const int left_label = 1, point_label = 2, right_label = 3;
    std::map<int, std::set<int>> orig_point_map;
    vector<pair<int,int>> pairs(2*starts.size()+points.size());
    int k = 0;
    for (auto& i : starts)
    {
        pairs[k++] = std::make_pair(i, left_label);
    }
    for (auto& i : ends)
    {
        pairs[k++] = std::make_pair(i, right_label);
    }
    for (auto i = 0;i < points.size();i++)
    {
        int point = points[i];
        pairs[k++] = std::make_pair(point, point_label);
        orig_point_map[point].emplace(i);
    }

    std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
    int coverage = 0;
    for (auto& x : pairs) {
        if (x.second == 1) {
            coverage++;
        }
        else if (x.second == 3) {
            coverage--;
        }
        else {
            std::set<int> indices = orig_point_map[x.first];
            for(auto i : indices) {
                cnt[i] = coverage;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: If this code works, it should be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You do extra copy with `std::set<int> indices = orig_point_map[x.first];`.

Comment: It's an assignment with time limit 4sec.

Comment: And what inputs? And how long did it take?

Comment: @Jarod42 Tried changing it but still exceeds the time limit.

Comment: @Useless The inputs are not known but it takes 4.34secs to complete.

Comment: "The inputs aren't known" - well, you'll have to write your own test program then, and then you can profile it

Comment: Try using `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>` for `cnt`. `std::map` has significantly larger constant than `std::sort`

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Same with `std::unordered_set` and `std::set`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the segments. Do we have `starts.size() == ends.size()` and there is so `starts.size()` segments consisting of `[starts[i];ends[i]]`. Or there is `starts.size() * ends.size()` segments, where segments are `[starts[i]; ends[j]]` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes starts and ends are of same size. The leftmost point of a segment is stored in starts and the rightmost in ends. Total number of segments is starts.size() or ends.size() because both are equal.

Comment: Replacing with  std::unordered_set and std::unordered_map increases the execution time to 5.34s.

Comment: You may get rid of most copies by sorting `starts`, `ends` individually, and iterate over ordered `points` `{value, index}`. (and by this fact, you should also reduce a little the complexity, as `(n log(n) + m log(m)) < (n+m)log(n+m)`).

Comment: @Jarod42 But for that 3 additional vectors(more copies) will be required because starts, ends and points vectors also have to be labelled, sorted and finally copied into points vector.

Comment: @user7301197: I mean something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e3b85e3b9149851).

Comment: @Jarod Thanks a lot! It worked. Max execution time was 0.08s. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas the complexity is good, you create a lot of copies which might be avoided.
You may use the modified version:

```
std::vector<int> fast_count_segments(std::vector<int> starts,
                                     std::vector<int> ends,
                                     const std::vector<int>& points) {
    std::vector<int> cnt(points.size());
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs(points.size());

    for (auto i = 0u; i != points.size(); ++i) {
        pairs[i] = std::make_pair(points[i], i);
    }
    std::sort(starts.begin(), starts.end());
    std::sort(ends.begin(), ends.end());
    std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
    int coverage = 0;
    auto it_start = starts.begin();
    auto it_end = ends.begin();
    for (auto& x : pairs) {

        while (it_start != starts.end() && *it_start <= x.first) {
            ++it_start;
            ++coverage;
        }
        while (it_end != ends.end() && *it_end < x.first) {
            ++it_end;
            --coverage;
        }
        cnt[x.second] = coverage;     
    }
    return cnt;
}
```